# EKEvent not passing title to view

Tags: objective-c, ekevent, ekeventstore

I'm having problems when creating a calendar event in my app, i have a collection view that have dates when you click one of them the view controller pops out without the name or date that i passed by code.

Here's the code:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
if([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]) {
    //This code will run when uses has made his/her choice
     EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
     [event setTitle:theTitle];
     event.startDate = date;
     event.endDate = date;
     EKEventEditViewController *controller = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];
     controller.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
     NSError *err;
     [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
     NSLog(@"err %@", err);
     controller.eventStore = eventStore;
     controller.editViewDelegate = self;
     [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

The code is in the
 
`-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Does `EKEventStore` have special methods to set the date or title?

Comment: What's the question / problem? What do you expect and what is actually happening?